# Java Optimization

Tags: java, optimization, short-circuiting

I want to know if java optimize this code?
Does it use Short-circuit (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) evaluation?

```
boolean c5 = A || B
boolean c4 = C && D
boolean c3 = E || F
boolean c2 = G && H

if ((c5) && (c4) && (c3) && (c2)){
  //execute operation
}
```

Comment: This is very easy for you to test yourself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It does use Short-circuit evaluation (represented by `&&` and `||` operators). Your condition

```
(c5) && (c4) && (c3) && (c2)
```

is essentially same as

```
(A || B) && (C && D) && (E || F) && (G && H)
```

which is same as

```
(A || B) &&  C && D  && (E || F) &&  G && H
```

so

- if `A` will be evaluated as `true` then `B` will not be tested.
- if `A` and `B` will be `false` then entire expression will be equal to

  ```
  false && C && D && (E || F) && G && H
  ```

  which is always `false` (because `false && whatever` is always `false`) so `C && D && (E || F) && G && H` will not be evaluated

and so on, and on...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, the operator && will short circuit the evaluation as soon as it finds a false condition, and || will do the same when finds a true.

> The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR operations on two boolean expressions. These operators exhibit "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is evaluated only if needed. [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

In case you would like to force the program to evaluate all the conditions you would have to use bitwise logical operators: & and |

For example:

```
if ((c5) & (c4) & (c3) & (c2)){
  //execute operation
}
```

The previous code would evaluate all conditions even if a false is found (non-short-circuiting).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

(`&&` and `||` short-circuit, as described in the Wikipedia page you linked)

Answer (score 0):

It does, you can check it yourself by running a code like:

```
boolean foo = true || func();
boolean bar = false && func();

public boolean func() {
     System.out.println("short circuit"); //not gonna see that line
     return true;

}
```